# UIActivityViewController completionWithItemsHandler function not called in MacOS app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uiactivityviewcontroller, mac-catalyst

**Background**

The function `shareImage()` in the code below launches the `UIActivityViewController` and shares an image, for example sends to Messages or saves to Photos.

After the image is shared, `UIActivityViewController` finishes up, and calls the `completionWithItemsHandler` function `activityComplete()`.

The code works fine and as expected on iOS / iPadOS / MacOS and shares the image, **EXCEPT that on MacOS, the `completionWithItemsHandler` function `activityComplete()` never gets called**, confirmed using the flag `print("Share complete.")`.

Xcode instead logs the following output:
`Scene destruction request failed with error: (null)`

---

**Question**

What could be causing the issue preventing the `completionWithItemsHandler` function `activityComplete()` from being called on MacOS, and how can this be corrected in code?

---

**Code**

*Note: Updated with two lines added based on the answer.*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var shareButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
    var activityImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Create share button
        shareButton.setTitle("Share", for:UIControl.State())
        shareButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: UIControl.State())
        shareButton.backgroundColor = .purple
        shareButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.shareImage), for:.touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(shareButton)
    }


    private var activity: UIActivityViewController?  // <-- Added
    
    @objc func shareImage() {
        
        // Take view screenshot
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0)
        self.view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height), afterScreenUpdates: false)
        activityImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        // Share view screenshot
        let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityImage as Any], applicationActivities: nil)
        
        // Present iPhone share options
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        // Present iPad share options
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
            if let popOver = activity.popoverPresentationController {
                popOver.sourceView = self.shareButton
            }
        }
        
        // Complete share
        activity.completionWithItemsHandler = {activity, success, items, error in
            self.activityComplete()
        }

        self.activity = activity  // <-- Added

    }
    
    func activityComplete() {
        
        print("Share complete.")
    }
}
```

Comment: "Xcode instead logs the following output"  Where?

Comment: The output is logged in the debug area in the console at the bottom of the Xcode window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to retain your activity view controller after presenting it.
Something like:

```
    private var activityViewController: UIActivityViewController?

    @objc func presentActivityViewController(activityItems: [Any]) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
            // some logic
        }
        self.activityViewController = activityViewController // <- retaining activityViewController
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "retain your activity view controller after presenting it"? What is missing in my code, that works fine on iOS and iPadOS but not on macOS?

Comment: Hey! I mean to set a local instance of UIActivityViewController to a private property in presenting view controller. Please check my updated comment with a code sample.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. These two lines made all the difference: 
 
private var activityViewController: UIActivityViewController? 
self.activityViewController = activityViewController 
 
Thanks for showing what to update in code.

Comment: Yes, retaining view controller solves the issues.